# Why code hint does not appear in Delphi XE3?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe3

I am using Delphi XE3 to develop a FireMonkey application. In the past, there is a code hint function, so that when I complete the name of a form, like this:

```
MainForm.
```

When I type the `.`, the IDE pops up a list of the functions and properties in the `MainForm` object. However, today I find such a function suddenly disappeared. Therefore, I wonder how to re-enable such a function again.

Comment: The feature you are looking for is called [Code Completion](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE3/en/Code_Completion), which is part of [Code Insight](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE3/en/Using_Code_Insight).

Comment: This feature is a little flaky, especially in older versions, sometimes it just stops working.

Comment: The most common cause is because code completion is turned off when debugging / running a project in the IDE. If you run the program you are working on and switch back to the source to make a quick change code completion is not available.

Comment: Code completion is handled by a different compiler known as the *kibbitz compiler* (different from the IDEs actual compiler and the command line compiler, which are also different from each other). That kibbitz compiler sometimes gets confused by code that (while technically correct) it can't quite figure out. When that code is located and changed to remove the confusion (sometimes a build will fix it, or saving/exiting/going back in), it usually starts working again.

Comment: I find out the reason. For some new added codes, the code completion will not come out until I perform a build on the project.